# Detecting split character in string

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Recently I had a Problem with Splitting a HTML string into separate columns in Access 2010 and store date in SQL server 2008R2 table. This works more or less because the number of lines varies.

To avoid storing the HTML-tags I have a easier solution, I use a text field in Access which is Formated as Standard while the other text-field is formated as rich-text to contain the Format.

Inserting the same content, which is copied from a HTML mail in the Standard text field maintains the LINE FEED !

How can I "detect" which character is it to replace it by another character for further use??

Example:

```
<div><font face=Arial size=3 color=black>Customer Name</font></div>
<div><font face=Arial size=3 color=black>Customer Address</font></div>
<div><font face=Arial size=3 color=black>12345 City</font></div>
```

is the copied Content from html mail and inserted into the rich-text field.

If I copy this Content to a Standard text field it Looks like this:

```
Customer Name
Customer Address
12345 City
```

In the Server table the Content of the field Looks like this

```
Customer Name  Customer Address  12345 City
```

But to maintain the line feed in the Access field there must be any character, but which??

Thanks!
Michael

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL-Server table, multiple rows are shown as one row. If you set the ControlSource property of the Access TextBox to that column, it will be shown with multiple lines.

If you still want to know the characters: It's a combination of the ASCII control characters CR and LF (chr(13) & chr(10) or vbCrLf or vbNewLine). In SQL-Server syntax it's CHAR(13)+CHAR(10).

Comment: Thanks your reply. Any idea HOW to replace those line feed characters by the string <BR />  ??

Comment: I don't know how your table and column are named, so i'll call the table "MyTable" and the column "MyColumn".

Comment: In Access syntax it should be:
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET MyColumn = Replace(MyColumn, vbCrLf, "<BR/>")

In SQL Server Syntax it's
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET MyColumn = Replace(MyColumn, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), "<BR/>")

Comment: Thanks a lot Dorian, I found a similar Response on the web too!